# In a SQL query, can I have different where clauses for different result columns?

Tags: sql

A contrived, example: say I have a simple table with 2 columns - date and (numeric) id.  I want to know, for each day, what percentage of the ids are even.

I can do this in 2 queries:

Query #1:

```
select date, id % 2, count(*) 
from my_table
group by date, id % 2
order by date, id % 2
```

Query #2:

```
select date, count(*) 
from my_table
group by date
order by date
```

And then I manually (i.e. in a spreadsheet) line up the columns and do the math.

This is cumbersome of course - is there a way to do this in one query?

Something like:

```
select 
    date, 
    [count where id % 2 = 0], [total count], 
    [count where id % 2 = 0 / total count] 
from my_table
group by date
order by date
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Also: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2):

Use a conditional `sum()`

```
select date, 
       sum(case when id % 2 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / count(*) as evenPercentage,
       sum(case when id % 2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / count(*) as unevenPercentage,
       count(*) as totalCount,
       sum(case when id % 2 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as evenCount,
       sum(case when id % 2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as unevenCount
from my_table
group by date
order by date
```